# Подскажите, почему возвращается не полный ответ на запрос?

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Origin': 'https://youla.ru',
    'Referer': 'https://youla.ru/?attributes[sort_field]=date_published',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'appId': 'web/3',
    'authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2OTg3MzUzODEsImlzcyI6InlvdWxhLmlvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3lvdWxhLmlvXC8iLCJzdWIiOiI2NTFjMDgwM2RiNGQ1ZTUxYmMwNGE0MTQiLCJ5b3VsYV9pZCI6IjY1MWMwODAzZGI0ZDVlNTFiYzA0YTQxMCIsInZrX2lkIjo4MjQ5NTI0MTUsInBob25lIjoiNDkxNTIxOTUzNzczNiIsImZpcnN0X25hbWUiOiJcdTA0MmZcdTA0NDFcdTA0NGYiLCJsYXN0X25hbWUiOiJcdTA0MWZcdTA0M2VcdTA0M2ZcdTA0M2VcdTA0MzJcdTA0MzAiLCJpbWFnZSI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9jZG4xLnlvdWxhLmlvXC9maWxlc1wvaW1hZ2VzXC9vcmlnXC82NVwvMWNcLzY1MWMwODAzZGI0ZDVlNTFiYzA0YTQxMi0yLmpwZyIsImV4cCI6MTY5ODczNTU2MX0.G6US5bWWIMlyVPAPc2Sb-RzQ7UTTCg-EApQkzh228-p4v9wpZbZ-y07K9u-z_TdSHVGXB4kpQQr3mnvUFThg4JVXswipEUs-xOrXk81LRsh6YPSDBfPGQRP51lRgZ5w7H0aWXPO9fgmdABErtHjc4x8JX8DmpXTE89MKRozf5j4',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'uid': '651ac72643188',
    'x-app-id': 'web/3',
    'x-offset-utc': '+11:00',
    'x-uid': '651ac72643188',
    'x-youla-splits': '8a=8|8b=7|8c=4|8m=5|8v=0|8z=8|16a=0|16b=0|64a=2|64b=0|100a=60|100b=55|100c=70|100d=12|100m=61',
}

json_data = {
    'operationName': 'catalogProductsBoard',
    'variables': {
        'sort': 'DATE_PUBLISHED_DESC',
        'attributes': [
            {
                'slug': 'categories',
                'value': [
                    '',
                ],
                'from': None,
                'to': None,
            },
        ],
        'datePublished': None,
        'location': {
            'latitude': None,
            'longitude': None,
            'city': None,
            'distanceMax': None,
        },
        'search': '',
        'cursor': '',
    },
    'extensions': {
        'persistedQuery': {
            'version': 1,
            'sha256Hash': '6e7275a709ca5eb1df17abfb9d5d68212ad910dd711d55446ed6fa59557e2602',
        },
    },
}

response = requests.post('https://api-gw.youla.io/graphql', headers=headers, json=json_data)

print(response.text)
```

возвращает пустой список товаров. где и что я упустил??

> [{"__typename":"LocationLabelPlacementItem"},{"__typename":"EmptyResultItem"},{"__typename":"AdvertItem"}]